# iOS app suffering short term memory loss

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Since the latest update, 1.3.1.213, the iOS app is stuck on the same post every time I launch it, even after backgrounding it for just a second.

It seems to be recalling its state when it enters the foreground, but not storing its updated state when going to the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in 1.3.1.214.

In the process of updating Google Analytics in CocoaPods, I needed to update AFNetworking.  AFNetworking has had some [ongoing issues](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2321) with extensions and CocoaPods so I [created a fix](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/2737) off of **`master`**.  I should have branched off of the last release because the commit just before mine introduced a regression where [a category clobbered the activity indicator's `dealloc` method](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/850e5e78503ee4a1170b1ac79139025ecf87a6a9#diff-c4328e077b8dce3a3d8adab067a19c4aR96) preventing an observer from being unregistered.  If the app had at any point shown a loading spinner and you backgrounded the app, the app would send a `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` to the deallocated instance crashing the app.

I've since submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/2741) to fix that issue and switched to [a branch off of the 2.5.4 release](https://github.com/bnickel/AFNetworking/tree/for-use).

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't getting a crash. It would just go back to an old view every time i restored the app from the background.

Comment: It was definitely crashing.  It crashed before saving where you were just at so it took you to the previously saved state.

Comment: Ohhh I get it. Wow the app launches so fast!

Comment: You were basically experiencing [this IRL](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)).

Comment: Defining `dealloc` of a framework class in a category?! Eeeek, with four 'e's.